# coinbase oauth2 sometimes failed to renew access token (using refresh token)

Tags: authentication, ios7, oauth-2.0

I am integrating coinbase in an iOS app and I am using Oauth2 to authenticate. I am able to get the access token after going through the usual workflow. I have also taken care to attempt refresh my access token whenever any requests hit a 401 (upon expiration) by calling this:

POST https://coinbase.com/oauth/token
Data:

grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=abcd1234&client_id=theclientid&client_secret=somesecretid

It works for a while but then from time to time, it would fail with a request response:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x15eb2730
{ URL: https://coinbase.com/oauth/token } { status code: 401, headers {
"CF-RAY" = "f67d477aae4052e-YYZ";
"Cache-Control" = "no-store";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Sun, 02 Feb 2014 15:14:14 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "cloudflare-nginx";
"Set-Cookie" = "__cfduid=<some long alpha-numeric string>; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.coinbase.com; HttpOnly";
Status = "401 Unauthorized";
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
"Www-Authenticate" = "Bearer realm=\"Doorkeeper\", error=\"invalid_request\", error_description=\"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed.\"";
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
"X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
"X-Request-Id" = "<some long alpha-numeric string>";
"X-Runtime" = "0.012066";
"X-Ua-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
} }
```

Has anyone encounter this error before? I have assume the request URL is correct always. I am not sure why it would complained about "missing required parameter" or "unsupported parameter". I havent figured out a pattern of failure yet. Hopefully, someone out there may have seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find any documentation directly about refresh_token requests, but I think you're supposed to also include the redirect_uri in your refresh_token request (based on this: https://coinbase.com/docs/api/authentication#collapse2).

Also, I noticed that my official coinbase app required a re-auth a few days ago, but when I log in to my coinbase account, it says that the app was authorized 25 days ago.  So, perhaps even the request_tokens have a timeout?  Did your request_token request fail after not using the app for a while?

Or maybe coinbase reset something and invalidated all of their access_tokens and refresh_tokens because my app, which was previously working fine as far as refresh_tokens, is now failing on the refresh_token request.

So, I would suggest having your app re-authorize when this happens, and get a new access_token and refresh_token, since I think that's what the official coinbase app does.