# Storing an access_token and refresh_token on the user model and using them again causes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, omniauth, coinbase-api

I'm using [omniauth-coinbase](https://github.com/coinbase/omniauth-coinbase) and [coinbase-ruby](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ruby) in my Rails app.

In my app, the user logs in via Coinbase which generates a `code` which I then turn into an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`.

I then create a new OAuth Client under the variable `coinbase` and it has full functionality.

```
user_credentials = {
    :access_token => access_token,
    :refresh_token => refresh_token,
    :expires_at => Time.now + 1.day
}
coinbase = Coinbase::OAuthClient.new(ENV['COINBASE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['COINBASE_CLIENT_SECRET'], user_credentials)
```

**Here's where the problem starts:**

I'm storing the `access_token` and the `refresh_token` on the User model as strings so that when the user comes back, I can either use two active tokens or use the `refresh_token` to generate two new tokens, as mentioned in section [here](https://coinbase.com/docs/api/authentication#oauth2) "Access Tokens and Refresh Tokens"

Coinbase exposes a `refresh!` method that I can call on my `coinbase` OAuth instance which *should* give me two new tokens.

`refresh!` works correctly after I generate a new OAuth Client but **not** when I pull existing tokens (valid or invalid) from the database off of the user model, create a `user_credentials` hash as noted above, instantiate a new OAuth Client, and then call `refresh!` on that.

As I understand from my research, the `access_token` expires. I use a `refresh_token` whenever to get both a new `access_token` and a new `refresh_token`. So in my mind, I should be able to instantiate a new OAuth Client, give it both keys and run a `refresh!` to put me back in working order and able to make valid calls to the Coinbase API.

Can anyone help out here as to what I may be doing wrong? Thanks!

**There error that I get from `refresh!` is as follows:**

```
OAuth2::Error: invalid_request: The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed.
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed."}
/Users/zackshapiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/oauth2-0.9.4/lib/oauth2/client.rb:113:in `request'
/Users/zackshapiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/oauth2-0.9.4/lib/oauth2/client.rb:138:in `get_token'
/Users/zackshapiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/oauth2-0.9.4/lib/oauth2/access_token.rb:86:in `refresh!'
/Users/zackshapiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/coinbase-2.0.0/lib/coinbase/oauth_client.rb:58:in `refresh!'
/Users/zackshapiro/dev/stopcoin/lib/tasks/short.rake:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/zackshapiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/Users/zackshapiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/Users/zackshapiro/dev/stopcoin/lib/tasks/short.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/zackshapiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/zackshapiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By implementing this on my own, I was both able to reproduce the described exception as well as create working code.

To reproduce the described exception, I had to use ***old tokens***. This consistently produced a `401 NOT AUTHORIZED` HTTP response when attempting to refresh again. This came about on accident by implementing a bug in my own refresh code. Although I had successfully persisted the tokens returned from the OAuth redirect, once I had refreshed to new tokens once, I forgot to persist the new ones back to the model. **NOTE:** Refreshing the token gives you both a new `access_token` AND `refresh_token` back.

Moving forward, the working code that I ended up with is as follows:

```
def test_refresh
  @old_tokens =
    {
      :access_token  => current_user.access_token,
      :refresh_token => current_user.refresh_token
    }

  client =
    Coinbase::OAuthClient.new \
      Rails.application.secrets.coinbase_api_key,
      Rails.application.secrets.coinbase_api_secret,
      @old_tokens

  new_token = client.refresh!

  @new_tokens =
    {
      :access_token  => new_token.token,
      :refresh_token => new_token.refresh_token
    }

  current_user.access_token  = @new_tokens[ :access_token ]
  current_user.refresh_token = @new_tokens[ :refresh_token ]
  current_user.save!
end
```

***[FULL WORKING EXAMPLE](https://github.com/cookrn/coinbase-oauth-test)***

The tokens are being persisted back to the user at the bottom, preventing old/expired tokens from being used.

Lastly, this may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513250/coinbase-oauth2-sometimes-failed-to-renew-access-token-using-refresh-token), though it is much less specific.

Comment: Thanks so much Ryan. The part I still don't understand is why my tokens were throwing the 401. They were brand new tokens I'd created and put on the user model. They hadn't expired and I made sure to replace both tokens and save each time I generated a new one

Comment: @ZackShapiro understood. It's hard to know exactly what was causing the issue without seeing more example code. Happy to attempt an update to the answer if more code is provided reproducing the error.

Comment: No need, I integrated the code from your app into my app, all things are working! Thanks again Ryan, been banging my head on this for days

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this error. Have you tried printing out all the relevant values before the call to Coinbase::OAuthClient.new? Make sure the client_id, client_secret, and user_credentials are all present and correct.

Also, it might be easier to just serialize the credentials hash directly to your User model. Check out our example rails app at https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-oauth-rails-example for reference.